# Как задать функции в UserScript

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, javascript

Код такой:

```
(function(window, undefined ) {
    var w;
    if (typeof unsafeWindow != undefined){
        w = unsafeWindow 
    } else {
        w = window;  
    }
    if (w.self != w.top){
        return;
    }
    if (/https?:\/\/(www\.)?linux.org.ru/.test(w.location.href)){

        //Содержание

    }
})(window);
```

Надо установить функции, которые будут запускаться из html, который будет добавлен скриптом, а также друг из друга.

Если пихать эти функции в содержание или задавать на главном уровне в скрипте - браузер (пока только в chrome проверяю) их при запуске не видит.

Естественно, пишу обыкновенно:

```
function foo (a, b) {
    //Содержание
}
```

Как же задавать функции в юзерскриптах?

---

upd.
**Решение:**

```
function contentEval(source) {
    source = '(' + source + ')();'
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = source;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    document.body.removeChild(script);
}

contentEval (function() {
    window.function1 = function(a,b){
        //...
    };
    window.function2 = function(c,d){
        //...
    };
});
```

Comment: интересно)<br>

не пробовал, но может сработать так:


    translate = function(obj){
      return function(){
        for( var key in obj )window[key] = obj[key];
      }
    }

    tr = {
     abc: function(){},
     bcd: function(){}
    };
    setTimeout( translate(tr), 1 );

Comment: Брр... Что-то не понял нифга. И куда функции пихать?

Comment: Это собственно UserScript, в переменной real - будет настоящий window

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример!!! того, что вы хотите:

```
(function( w ) {
    if (w.self != w.top){
        return;
    }

    if (/https?:\//.test(w.location.href)){
      w.document.body.innerHTML += 
        '<div '+
          'style = "'+
            'position:absolute;'+
            'top:100px;'+
            'left:500px;'+
            'background-color:red;'+
            'width:200px;'+
            'height:200px;'+
          '"'+
          'id = "test"'+
        '>'+
            '<center>test_of_click</center>'+
        '</div>';

      w.document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(){
        alert('test working');
      }
    }
})( window || unsafeWindow );
```

Добавить что-то новое в основной namespace - у меня не получилось...

Comment: Отсюда взял: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/129343/
Как ты предлагаешь - это решит сабж?

Comment: К сожалению, не то. Уже все написано - надо только прикрутить. Там функция с многих объектов вызывается с разными аргументами.